# how to join two different datasets in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two different datasets source and destination datsets

```
Source Dataset
Type      A         B   C   D   E   F   G
X         1         2   3   4   5   6   7
Y         2         1   3   5   6   7   8
Z         3         4   5   6   7   8   9

Destination Dataset                         
Type    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
X       0   2   3   6   3   7   9
Y       1   1   5   5   4   8   0
Z       2   3   4   4   5   9   9
```

Is it possible two create a report in the following format?

```
       Type A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Source  X   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
Destin  X   0   2   3   6   3   7   9
Source  Y   2   1   3   5   6   7   8
Destin  Y   1   1   5   5   4   8   0
Source  Z   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Destin  Z   2   3   4   4   5   9   9
```

Comment: You might need to format your question a bit better - it's difficult to understand what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Handle this in **SQL** itself with query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'Source' AS myField, Type, A, B, C, D, E, F, G
   FROM Table1 T1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Destination' AS myField, Type, A, B, C, D, E, F, G
   FROM Table1 T2 ) A
ORDER BY myField Desc, Type
```

It will be better way instead of handling it in SSRS.

To solve it in SSRS, you would need to know if the `Types` in both the datasets are mutually exclusive or not. If there are `Types` which exists in one but not in other, then you would have to do lot of hardcoding. All changes in the input data you would need to change the report. If the types in both dataset are not mutually exclusive then you *might* be able to use `Lookup functions`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Lookup functionality, 
OR instead of doing the join in SSRS it's better to do this is in SQL.

Comment: User expects answer, descriptions not links :(

Comment: Lookup is not present in SSRS-2008.

Comment: Lookup is there in SSRS 2008.